# JavaScript Google map marker bug

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project where I'm using the Google Maps API to show a marker for every company that's registrated in the database.

Everything works just fine, but when I click on a marker the tooltip/dialogbox for the last company in my company list always shows up and not the actualy company mark that's been clicked on.

I can't really get my head around why it is always the last marker that shows up. Here's my **updated** code:

```
JavaScript.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                  function load() {
                  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
                    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(56.4, 10.57983), 9);
                    map.enableScrollWheelZoom();

                   }
               }
         </script> ";

    foreach (MemberProfile m in relatedMembers)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        string address = m.Address;
        string zip = m.Zip;
        string city = m.City;
        string navn = m.Name;
        string tlf = m.Phone;

        doc.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + zip + "+" + city + "+" + address + "+DK&sensor=true&key=ABQIAAAAEaY4JLb9fZFGMlDKuMUlWBRSvyGIkBO7X03pzlT7Z30EPXHR8BS0rXL_ShFm2gc79lZTw2Zak88wng");

        XmlNode latNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()");
        XmlNode lonNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()");

        if (latNode != null && lonNode != null)
        {
            JSAddMarkers.Text += @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + latNode.Value + "," + lonNode.Value + ")); " 
                             + "var html = '<b>" + navn + "</b><br />" + address + "<br /> " + zip + " " + city + "<br />" + tlf + "'; " + "GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html); });"
                             + "map.addOverlay(marker);"
                             + "</script>";
        }
```

If any of you out there can spot the reason why, I would be happy to hear from you! Any help/hint is appreciated :-)

All the best,

Bo

Comment: I guess the glitch is in the order of creating map object and adding markers on it. You should first create the map object and then execute the loop to add markers to it.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right on this one! I will update my first post with my new code where I moved the creation of the map above the foreach loop. There's no markers showing up on the map though :/ Might have missed something along the road..

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this :( I have tried to refactor my code a lot so it outputs one <script></script> snippet with all the markers added. Still it only displays the last marker for every point there is. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var point =new GLatLng(" + latNode.Value + "," + lonNode.Value + ");
var marker = createMarker(point, address,zip,city,navn);
map.addOverlay(marker);



function createMarker(point, address, zip,city, navn) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, customIcons[type]);
      var html = "Address:<b style='padding-left:6px'>" + address+ "</b><br/>zip:<b  style='padding-left:6px'>"+ zip+ "</b><br/>city:<b  style='padding-left:6px'>"+ city+ "</b>";
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
                 marker.closeInfoWindow();
   });
      return marker;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bhanu, that's definately also a way to do it. But since i'm working with javascript ninja-coding in C# codebehind it seems like I have a a little trouble to get your code to work :/ Never really worked with javascript in codebehind before, so bear with me..